# What is the meaning of poly(x,2)2?

Tags: r, polynomials

I'm currently conducting a statistical test on unimodality but I'm a little unsure about the R-output:

[image: R output]

I'm curious about the difference between the meanings of `poly(X, 2)1` and `poly(X, 2)2`?

Comment: Check out the `?poly` help page for some info. Otherwise it's easier to help if you provide a proper [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with data and code that we can run (rather than an image) so we can exactly answer your question.

Comment: Those are the coefficients of `X` and `X^2`, respectively, in your model.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `poly(Dat$X, 2)`, you get a matrix with two columns, named "1" and "2". `poly(X, 2)1` and `poly(X, 2)2` in your output refer to those two columns.

Comment: Thank you! With my output is it therefore safe to say there is a quadratic relationship and significant unimodal response?